# How to get back my project code in VScode after deleting the code from GitHub Desktop. Code is not find but build folder works on live server

Tags: reactjs, github, visual-studio-code

How to get back my code in VScode after deleting from GitHub Desktop.
And my website works on build folder on live server of VScode but code is not showing in VScode. How to get back my code in VScode.

Is it possible to delete file from GitHub Desktop then it will Remove from VScode

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.